# react native LayoutAnimation spring animation after component mounts

Tags: react-native

When the component (**MenuBtn**) mounts, I want to increase the size of the button from 0 to 50 in a spring popping way. But instead I am having to problems:

1. No only the **MenuBtn** animates, but also the **Text component** ("Heading").
2. The first mounting animation is not a spring type, but in a fadingIn kind of way. But the *showMenu()* animates in a spring type.

What am I missing here? How can I make only the MenuBtn pop up when it loads and not all the components.

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text style={styles.header}>Heading</Text>
                <View style={styles.wrapper}>
                    <MenuBtn/>
                </View>
            </View>
        )
    }
}

class MenuBtn extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            radius: 0,
            degree: '0deg',
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        LayoutAnimation.spring();
        this.setState({
            radius: 50,
        });
    }

    showMenu = () => {
        LayoutAnimation.spring();
        this.setState({
            radius: this.state.radius == 60 ? 50 : 60,
            degree: this.state.degree == '45deg' ? '0deg' : '45deg',
        })
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={this.showMenu}>
                <View style={{ width: this.state.radius, height: this.state.radius, borderRadius: this.state.radius/2, transform: [{rotateZ: this.state.degree}],}}>
                    <Icon name="plus" size={30} color="white"/>
                </View>
            </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: As for 1 - Try using `LayoutAnimation.configureNext` insread.

Comment: @NirH Sorry, but that didn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `LayoutAnimation` API is simple to use, but doesn't offer a lot of customizability.  When you call `LayoutAnimation.spring()`, or any of the other LayoutAnimation methods, you are effectively saying "animate **all** UI changes that happen during this render cycle".

Instead, you could use the [Animated](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/animated.html) API to gain more control the type and target of the animation. Because it's a lower-level API, this requires a bit more code.

For simple transitions like this one, I would recommend using the excellent [react-native-animatable](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-animatable) library, which makes entry transitions as easy as wrapping your element in an `Animatable.View` and specifying one of the many available transitions:

```
<Animatable.View animation='bounceIn'>
  // your component
</Animatable.View>
```

Comment: Okay! And react-native-animatable looks promising.